# How to change logo in gitea

Tags: postgresql, image, docker, favicon, gitea

I just installed Gitea with Postgres using docker-compose, how can I change the gitea logo with the one i want.[image]

and :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Follow [the fine documentation for replacing the logo](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/customizing-gitea/#changing-the-logo).

Since you are running gitea in docker either you have to provide the files inside the container, or take a dockerish approach and bind-mount another logo from the host's filesystem.